# Using "wollen" in passive

Tags: grammar, passive, modal-verb

I came across this sentence

> Auch 25 Jahre nach dem Fall der Berliner Mauer gibt es noch viele Barrieren, die überwunden werden wollen.

My question is: Can things, like barriers, "want to be overcome"? Isn't it the people that want to overcome these things?

If so, why is this usage correct (or not)?

Comment: wollen is not in passive voice, it is wollen + an infinitive passive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The form „etwas will getan sein“ *(something needs to be done)* is correct.

Duden – Deutsches Universalwörterbuch, 5. Aufl. Mannheim 2003:

> **wollen**
>   (…)
>   **f)** <in Verbindung mit einem 2. Part. u. »sein« od. »werden«> drückt aus, dass etw. eine bestimmte Bemühung, Anstrengung o. Ä. verlangt; *müssen:* etw. will gekonnt sein; dieser Schritt will gut überlegt werden;
>   (…)

Duden – Das Stilwörterbuch, 9. Aufl. Mannheim 2010:

> **wollen**
>   (…)
>   **3.** <in Verbindung mit dem 2. Partizip mit *sein* oder *werden*> *müssen:* dieser Schritt, diese Entscheidung will gut überlegt, nicht übereilt sein; so eine Sache will vorsichtig angefasst, behandelt werden; Autofahren will gelernt sein.
>   (…)

Comment: It is even possible to use it on impersonal verbs: "Es will einfach nicht regnen", expressing that rain is long overdue.

Answer (score 2):

"Barrieren, die überwunden werden wollen" is correct, because "Barriere" is treated as if it were a person (this is a stylistic device called "personification").

In reality, this refers to barriers that exist between people, with the hope that the people will sooner or later overcome these barriers.